# set property type dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, parsing, reflection, types, properties

I got the following problem with my data stream:

The data stream consists of a  dictionary, which I want to parse and specify the type of the value dynamically.

I.e. my data strea includes:

- "date", "01.01.2000"
- "name", "joe"
- "alive", "true"
- "health", "100"

Now I would like to set my properties of a generic class according to this data stream:

```
class GenericClass
{
    Hashtable genericAttributes;
}
```

Is there a possibility to set my values of the data stream to the correct type via reflection?

I could try something like:

```
DateTime.TryParse(date, out myDate);
```

for the date time object, but I don't think this will work when trying to parse doubles, floats, int16s, int32s, uint16,...

Some thoughts on that?

Thx and regards

Comment: There is also `Double.TryParse`, `Float.TryParse`, `Short.TryParse`, and `Int32.TryParse`, etc. etc.

Comment: where do you get the eventual `Type` from?

Comment: Yes, I know, but that would leave me with the problem that "2.0" maybe converted into an Int16, an float and double.

Comment: all of them are strings anyway,you need a way to specify the target type for each of them in your stream.

Comment: @MarcGravell I want to get the Type from the way my data could be parsed. I.e. by trying to parse it into a datetime object, I would know if it is a date time object.

Comment: @ffyhlkain and is `"123"` a double? a float? an int? a byte? or a string that happens to contain digits? personally, I would say that is a bit risky, but: as Cory notes: if you *want* to do that, just use the various TryParse

Comment: @CodeIgnoto So I couldn't do something like saying a property "<code>myGenericProperty</code>, you are a date time object" and declaring the property as <code>System.Object myGenericProperty</code>?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, I know it's risky. I wouldn't do it if I hadn't do it this way. So maybe I'll try this long TryParse thing and hope it will work this way.

Comment: If you answer @MarcGravell I might be able to give you some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess from your question is that they all are `IConvertible`, so I would do something my code example below. The idea is that I specify the "want"-order, ie in the order I want the types if they can fit multiple types, and then I try to convert them in that order.

```
    public class GenericPropClass
    {
        public Type type;
        public object value;
        public string key;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void PropertySet()
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var resultingList = new List<GenericPropClass>();
        // Specify the order with most "specific"/"wanted" type first and string last
        var order = new Type[] { typeof(DateTime), typeof(int), typeof(double), typeof(string) }; 

        foreach (var key in dict.Keys)
            foreach (var t in order)
            {
                try
                {
                    var res = new GenericPropClass()
                    {
                        value = Convert.ChangeType(dict[key], t),
                        key = key,
                        type = t,
                    };
                    resultingList.Add(res);
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // Just continue
                }
            }

    }
```

Sorry for a short answer containing almost only code, I might have time to improve it tonight to get my thoughts in, but I have to go now :)